# Django 1.11 filter by time delta between latest and next to latest

Tags: django, django-orm, timedelta

Let's imagine we have an Event model:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    actor = models.ForeignKey(Actor, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    happened_datetime = models.DateTimeField(_('When did the event took place?'), blank=False, null=False)
```

and an actor model:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, default='')
```

After a while, we have a potentially long list of events.

How should we go about to get the actors whose latest two events are separated by less or more than a specified timedelta, for example:

> Give me all actors whose latest and next to latest events are not separated by more than 10 days

or

> Give me all actors whose latest and next to latest events are not separated by less than 5 hours

Is a `Subquery` the way to go? An `ExpressionWrapper` with `F` expressions?

Note: the above queries means we should also filter by Actors who have caused at least two events, with something similar to this:

```
actors_with_at_least_two = Actor.objects.annotate(
    nb_events=Subquery(
        Event.objects.filter(
            actor=OuterRef('pk')
        ).values(
            'actor__pk'
        ).order_by().annotate(
            cnt=Count('*')
        ).values('cnt')[:1],
        output_field=models.IntegerField()
    )
).filter(
    nb_events__gte=2
)
```

The above works well, but filtering with "introspection" on same table (timedelta, etc) I struggle with. Any ideas/clue would be kindly appreciated! :-)

I have tried with the following:

```
events = Event.objects.annotate(
    delta_with_previous=Subquery(
        Event.objects.filter(
            actor=OuterRef('actor__pk')
        ).exclude(
            pk=OuterRef('pk')
        ).latest(
          'happened_datetime'
        ).values(
          'actor__pk'
        ).order_by().values(
          'happened_datetime'
        )[:1],
        output_field=models.DurationField
    )
).filter(
    delta_with_previous__lte=timedelta(days=2)
).order_by(
    'actor__pk'
)
```

But it does not seem to work just well enough.